# Python List Comprehension One Line

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Assuming 'a' is a list that contains (for example) [2,4,2,3,3,3]

```
for i in a:
    if a.count(i) == i:
        a.remove(i)
```

How can I convert the code to one line using list comprehenstion, lambda, filter or something diffrent.

Comment: No, my goal is to remove only one of the N elemnts that got N numbers.

Comment: For example, if a is [2,3,3,2,4,4] the output will be: [2,3,3,4,4] because only 2 got N elemnts as N (two elemnts of two) .

Comment: @HelpPleasee that kind of information is best in your question.

Comment: And what exactly is `N`? You really need to edit your question to make it clear just what you are asking.

Comment: And you want this as a one-liner... why? Is it a homework assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never remove items from a list while iterating over it, the iteration gets messed up and you won't get the desired result.

```
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(a) if a.count(x) != x or a.index(x) != i]
[4, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's not what I meant.

Comment: @HelpPleasee then clarify what you meant.

Comment: For ecample, if a is [2,3,3,2,4,4]
the output will be: [2,3,3,4,4]
because only 2 got N elemnts as N (two elemnts of two)

Comment: @HelpPleasee so you actually do want to remove just one of each of the relevant values, i.e. what I had guessed you didn't want?

Comment: HallIn your answer, all the values that got N elemnts got deleted, not only one

Comment: @HelpPleasee OK I've edited the answer. However it's O(n^2) which is very slow. Is it important to remove the *first* occurrence of these numbers, or is it OK to remove any one? For example is `[2, 4, 3, 3]` acceptable output?